# Visual Basic: Uploading a file using HTTP

Tags: http, file-upload, vbscript

I'm a PHP / Javascript developer having to build a "simple" script that will run on a windows desktop that transfers a scanned image to a server.  By using a .vbs script I have been able to do everything I need to do except send the file to the server.  I have spent the last two days googling and trying examples, but nothing seems to work.  Below is the code I'm currently fighting with.

```
Dim objShell,UserPath,sourcePath,strURL,stream, file, fileString, HTTPSevice, body
Set objshell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
UserPath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")

strURL = "www.notWebsite.com/uploader.php"
sourcePath = UserPath & "\Desktop\Scanned\scanned.jpg"

set stream = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
set file = stream.getfile(sourcePath)
set fileString = file.openAsTextstream
body = fileString.readAll
fileString.close

set xmlHttp = createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0")
xmlhttp.open "POST",strURL,false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
xmlhttp.send body

msgbox xmlhttp.responseText
```

The code doesn't throw an error, it just sends an empty request to the server.

Like I said before, I have no experience with developing for/on/near windows, so if a visual basic script isn't the right option, please let me know and point me in the right direction.   I'm willing to learn how to make this work, but I'm just stuck on how to move forward.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: Have a look at ["Post binary data to URL from WSH/ASP/VBA/VBScript"](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_post-binary-data-url/). But you should reealy change your technology and think about using PowerShell. It's easier to use for a PHP/JS Developer and has no problems uploading files...

Comment: Thank you!  I haven't see that link, I'll definitely read over it now.  I'll also look into PowerShell today.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell is 100% the way to go for my usecase.  Even though I've never heard of it before this morning, I already have the script working and ready for testing.

Comment: Nice to hear! Would you like to share your script with us to support other users with similar questions?